# No access to my variable outside do-catch block in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift2

I'm trying to pass responseDict to self.saveApiTokenInKeychain(responseDict) but it's saying it's an unresolved identifier. Before I implemented the Do-Catch block it was working fine. How do I make it accessible to that method again?

```
httpHelper.sendRequest(httpRequest, completion: {(data:NSData!, error:NSError!) in
    //show error
    if error != nil {
        let errorMessage = self.httpHelper.getErrorMessage(error)
        self.displayAlertMessage("Error", alertDescription: errorMessage as String)

        return
    } 
    //hide activity indicator and update userLoggedInFlag
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true
    self.updateUserLoggedInFlag()

    var jsonerror:NSError?

    do {
        let responseDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.domain)")
    }
    var stopBool : Bool

    //save API AuthToken and ExpiryDate in Keychain
    self.saveApiTokenInKeychain(responseDict)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your responseDict is not in scope when you call

```
self.saveApiTokenInKeychain(responseDict)
```

Move the declaration of responseDict out of the do-catch like this:

```
var responseDict: WhateverTheTypeIs
do {
    responseDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.domain)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it